# Create-react-app deployment failure on Digital Ocean using dokku

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, dokku

I am trying to deploy create-react-app on digital ocean droplet using dokku. I have been successful on my previous deployments, however this app is failing at last. please help me to resolve the issue. Below is my package.json file and dokku logs

**Dokku Logs .....**

```
Enumerating objects: 465, done.
Counting objects: 100% (465/465), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (441/441), done.
Writing objects: 100% (465/465), 6.56 MiB | 1.87 MiB/s, done.
Total 465 (delta 162), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (162/162), done.
-----> Cleaning up...
-----> Building jb from herokuish...
-----> Adding BUILD_ENV to build environment...
-----> Node.js app detected

-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false

-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  14.3.0
       engines.npm (package.json):   6.14.4

       Resolving node version 14.3.0...
       Downloading and installing node 14.3.0...
       Bootstrapping npm 6.14.4 (replacing 6.14.5)...
       npm 6.14.4 installed

-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules

       > core-js@2.6.11 postinstall /tmp/build/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
       > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


       > fsevents@1.2.12 install /tmp/build/node_modules/fsevents
       > node-gyp rebuild

       make: Entering directory '/tmp/build/node_modules/fsevents/build'
       SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/.node
       COPY Release/.node
       make: Leaving directory '/tmp/build/node_modules/fsevents/build'

       > core-js@3.6.5 postinstall /tmp/build/node_modules/core-js
       > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


       > core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall /tmp/build/node_modules/core-js-pure
       > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


       > node-sass@4.14.1 install /tmp/build/node_modules/node-sass
       > node scripts/install.js

       Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.14.1/linux-x64-83_binding.node
       Download complete
       Binary saved to /tmp/build/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-83/binding.node
       Caching binary to /tmp/npmcache.xZLNQ/_cacache/node-sass/4.14.1/linux-x64-83_binding.node

       > node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall /tmp/build/node_modules/node-sass
       > node scripts/build.js

       Binary found at /tmp/build/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-83/binding.node
       Testing binary
       Binary is fine
       added 2013 packages in 104.582s

-----> Build
       Running build

       > jeewitbachan@0.1.0 build /tmp/build
       > NODE_ENV=production react-scripts build

       Creating an optimized production build...
       Compiled successfully.

       File sizes after gzip:

       127.29 KB  build/static/js/7.328a849a.chunk.js
       47.8 KB    build/static/js/0.5abe17cc.chunk.js
       19.23 KB   build/static/js/main.52fbfc8f.chunk.js
       5.55 KB    build/static/css/7.31d7db73.chunk.css
       2.11 KB    build/static/css/main.41b254e4.chunk.css
       1.84 KB    build/static/js/8.7746b82b.chunk.js
       1.8 KB     build/static/js/2.921fe7b4.chunk.js
       1.61 KB    build/static/js/runtime-main.7b6f0658.js
       1.48 KB    build/static/js/3.c310beb4.chunk.js
       1.04 KB    build/static/css/2.db2e41ff.chunk.css
       986 B      build/static/js/9.d50ea308.chunk.js
       912 B      build/static/js/10.5ef69429.chunk.js
       782 B      build/static/js/11.4fa4b5c3.chunk.js
       526 B      build/static/js/4.7d8f5389.chunk.js
       496 B      build/static/css/8.0a5c9922.chunk.css
       392 B      build/static/js/12.23118763.chunk.js
       338 B      build/static/js/1.719d2a52.chunk.js
       308 B      build/static/css/10.eef0e758.chunk.css
       307 B      build/static/css/9.eef0e758.chunk.css

       The project was built assuming it is hosted at /.
       You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.

       The build folder is ready to be deployed.
       You may serve it with a static server:

       npm install -g serve
       serve -s build

       Find out more about deployment here:

       bit.ly/CRA-deploy


-----> Caching build
       - node_modules

-----> Pruning devDependencies
       audited 2513 packages in 26.269s

       62 packages are looking for funding
       run `npm fund` for details

       found 2 low severity vulnerabilities
       run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Releasing jb (dokku/jb:latest)...
-----> Deploying jb (dokku/jb:latest)...
-----> App Procfile file found (/home/dokku/jb/DOKKU_PROCFILE)
-----> DOKKU_SCALE file not found in app image. Generating one based on Procfile...
       DOKKU_SCALE declares scale -> web=1
=====> Processing deployment checks
       No CHECKS file found. Simple container checks will be performed.
       For more efficient zero downtime deployments, create a CHECKS file. See http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/deployment/zero-downtime-deploys/ for examples
-----> Attempting pre-flight checks (web.1)
       Waiting for 10 seconds ...
remote: App container failed to start!!
=====> jb web container output:
       > jeewitbachan@0.1.0 start /app
       > react-scripts start
       ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.17.0.4/
       ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from 
       ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
       ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
       Starting the development server...
=====> end jb web container output
To 165.227.87.8:jb
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'dokku@165.227.87.8:jb'
```

**Package.json file**

```
{
  "name": "jeewitbachan",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.3.0",
    "npm": "6.14.4"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "npm": "^6.14.4",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-helmet": "^6.0.0",
    "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^3.10.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.1",
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development react-scripts start",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Note:- I have noticed on dokku logs that i says "Starting the development server...." does that mean it is still deployed in dev mode or have i done anything wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I finally resolved the issue after downgrading to "react-scripts": "3.4.0". Yeah!!